# How to add customer email to order grid in magento 1.4

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have found several ways online but none seem to work.   Does anyone know how to add the customer email to the grid for orders in Magento 1.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

copy
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
to
 
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

then under the following line

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());`

add

`$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email'));`

then in the _prepareColumns() method add

```
    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'index' => 'customer_email',
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.customer_email',
    ));
```

note. you will need to add a 'filter_index' to all calls to addColumn pointing to main_table.field_name

Comment: This answer works perfectly!  However, I've run into an issue when trying to _extend_ Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid rather than simply copying it locally.  `_prepareCollection` returns `parent::_prepareCollection`.  If you extend the class, then returning `parent::_prepareCollection` undoes the customization to the collection.  I think extending classes is more elegant that copying locally so I get updates to other code in the class if I upgrade the Mage core, but how can I make this work properly?

Comment: Works on 1.5.1.0 as well

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$collection->getSelect()
               ->join(
               'sales_flat_order_address',
               'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id AND      sales_flat_order_address.address_type="shipping"', array('sales_flat_order_address.email'
=> 'email'));
```